# Alternative to Kinect for projection mapping

Tags: 3d, mapping, kinect, projection

I'm looking for an alternative to Kinect. So far I´ve found Asus Xtion Pro that may be the closest but 
I'm not sure if anyone has done projection mapping on this device.

However I cannot use Kinect because i'm not allowed to do so for my project.

Anyone know any alternatives or projects/sites that have used Asus Xtion or an alternative to do skeletal mapping?

Answer (score 0):

With the OpenNI SDK you can do skeletal tracking, and this SDK is available with the kinect, the Asus Xtion Pro and the Primesense carmine sensor.

The github of the SDK : https://github.com/OpenNI